# Unknown exception when uploading new version of file via Box java sdk

Tags: box-api, box

I was trying to upload a new version of a file to Box via box Java SDK.
Upon uploading I got this exception.

> com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: Couldn't finish closing the connection to
>   the Box API due to a network error or because the stream was already
>   closed.   at
>   com.box.sdk.BoxAPIResponse.disconnect(BoxAPIResponse.java:159)    at
>   com.box.sdk.BoxFile.uploadVersion(BoxFile.java:471)   at
>   com.box.sdk.BoxFile.uploadVersion(BoxFile.java:440)   at
>   com.box.sdk.BoxFile.uploadVersion(BoxFile.java:430)   at
>   com.mstack.dig.store.box.Box.uploadData(Box.java:102)     at
>   com.mstack.dig.service.UploadServiceImpl.uploadFiles(UploadServiceImpl.java:41)
>     at
>   com.mstack.dig.controller.UploadController.uploadIndices(UploadController.java:39)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: stream is closed  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.ensureOpen(HttpURLConnection.java:3309)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3334)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3329)
>     at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIResponse.disconnect(BoxAPIResponse.java:149)
>     ... 40 more

But I've noted that the file is successfully uploaded as a new version. Is this any kind of an issue with API ?

Code snippet that I've used :-

```
 byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
 inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
 boxFile = new BoxFile(api, fileId); 
 boxFile.uploadVersion(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out why this is happening. But even after this exception,my file upload works fine. So we can ignore this and continue with upload.