# How to keep track changes in Box api without long polling

Tags: box-api, box

I've a system that keep tracks all files in box account. I want to know how we can keep track of changes or incremental updates in box account without using long polling. I've worked with dropbox and there's a nice feature to *delta poll* using a ***cursor*** with which we can get the incremental updates only. Is there any similar feature in Box to do this ?

Comment: Is this for a client or server application?

Comment: @JohnHoerr   Can you answer this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544546/unknown-exception-when-uploading-new-version-of-file-via-box-java-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [Box API's Events endpoint](https://docs.box.com/reference#get-events-for-a-user) lets you request these incremental changes. The documentation refers to the cursor as the stream position.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you answer this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544546/unknown-exception-when-uploading-new-version-of-file-via-box-java-sdk